# How to get rid of reference in beamer presentation menu

Tags: beamer, biblatex, header-footer

The following code causes the text `References` in the top left hand side of the slide. I've tried lots and lots of things but I don't seem to be able to get rid of the text. (Redefining `\bibname` doesn't work, and using the option `title={}` for the `\printbibliography` command also doesn't work.)

(Oddly enough, when I use the same code for the `block` with the `beamer-poster` package, using the option `name={\hbox to 1mm{}}` *does* get rid of the text. Other names don't....)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tiny}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   Some citation~\cite{Knuth:1990}.
   \begin{block}{Bibliography}
      \printbibliography[name={}]
   \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The following is the BibTeX file, which should be called `tiny.bib`.

```
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    keywords  = {latex},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison--Wesley},
}
```

Comment: With `\addbibresource`, one should *not* omit the file extension (normally, `.bib`).

Comment: @lockstep Thanks. I didn't know this. It has always worked for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the optional argument of `\printbibliography`, replace `name={}` with `heading=none`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    keywords  = {latex},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison--Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   Some citation~\cite{Knuth:1990}.
   \begin{block}{Bibliography}
      \printbibliography[heading=none]
   \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note: The `filecontents` package/environment makes life easier for potential answerers.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comment about the `filecontents` package.

Answer (score 2):

I spent lot of time to find out how to solve exactly this issue, when bibtex command `\bibliography{biblio}` is used (LyX produces this construct by default).

At the end this solution worked:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsubsection*{\bibname }}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).